# JavaScript - ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, websocket

Focusing on the client side API only (because each server side language will have its own API), the following snippet opens a connection, creates event listeners for connect, disconnect, and message events, sends a message back to the server, and closes the connection using WebSocket.

```
// Create a socket instance
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

// Open the socket
socket.onopen = function(event) {

    // Send an initial message
    socket.send('I am the client and I\'m listening!');

    // Listen for messages
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('Client received a message',event);
    };

    // Listen for socket closes
    socket.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log('Client notified socket has closed',event);
    };

    // To close the socket....
    socket.close()

};
```

**But I am getting an error on executing above snippet:**

> ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

I have gone through various links like https://davidwalsh.name/websocket, on how to implement WebSockets. But none of them are importing any **npm package**.

**Question:** So, how to implement WebSockets (client side AngularJS)? What am I missing here?

Comment: Like @Brad mentioned your question is client sided. For Serverside I would recommend [Socket.io](https://socket.io/), which also has some sample code up. Both server and client sided

Comment: Thanks @Templum. I have worked briefly on Socket.io
I want to learn WebSockets.

Comment: Make sure you are running the code in the browser and not in NodeJS, also use a modern [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) that supports it

Comment: @OmriLuzon but I want to implement it on client side - AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're referencing in your question is client-side code.  WebSocket is available directly in browsers.

For your Node.js server-side code, look at the [ws NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws).

> So, how to implement WebSockets (client side) on NodeJS?

You don't.  Node.js is server-side, not client-side.

Comment: He can still use it to connect as a client, he just needs the right module for that

Comment: @OmriLuzon Obviously, but that's not really the question though, despite the way it's worded.  The error message clearly indicates that the person asking tried to run client-side code with Node.js on the server.

Comment: Okay, your answer makes sense. So foolish of me. But if I were to use it on client side (AngularJS) then how to make it work? @Brad

Comment: @Brad But then it is throwing ReferenceError like mentioned above.

Comment: @kshikhar Not if you use it in a modern browser, it won't.

Comment: On the server side (nodeJS) which WebSocket servers are available? @Brad

Comment: @kshikhar As I said in my answer, server-side, use `ws`.

Comment: Okay, and what about socket.io? Can I use socket.io on server-side? @Brad

Comment: @kshikhar Sure, if you use a Socket.IO client on the client-side.  Socket.IO isn't necessarily web socket.  Web socket is a transport it can use, but it can use others.

Answer (score 46):

Try

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
```

Then

> npm i ws

and retry. It's work with my case

Comment: Thanks. Nice tip!

Comment: This one combined with the accepted one should be the final answer.

Answer (score 17):

I'm leaving this here for people having trouble with the `@stomp/stompjs` package in a node app.

Add this line:

`Object.assign(global, { WebSocket: require('ws') });`

also, don't forget to `npm install ws`

Comment: It seems like `@stomp/stompjs` is not the only package with a missing dependency on Websocket. In my case it was `fast-xml-parser` (or one of its dependencies).

Comment: Thank you for this. This solution works even in vs code plugin development.

Comment: Guess when importing: `import WebSocket from "ws"; Object.assign(global, { WebSocket: WebSocket });`

Answer (score 4):

When you are trying to run JavaScript, usually, you run it either in Browser or in NodeJS.

Browser and NodeJS are different JavaScript runtime.

WebSocket itself is a application layer protocol, you need to use API to employ it.

Currently(05-Dec-2019),

most browsers support WebSocket API for developer to use WebSocket.

NodeJS does not provide any OOTB API for developer to use WebSocket, you need 3rd lib to use WebSocket (e.g. https://github.com/websockets/ws).

The example you followed is using WebSocket API in browser.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error on your Browser console, it is important to check the spelling and capitalization. Make sure that "WebSocket" starts with capital letter. Otherwsie, it could throw reference error.

```
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080")
```